# 3 tables on sequelize: lost with relations

Tags: sequelize.js

I attached table structures:

I constructed the SQL

This is my sql :

SELECT 
  criticites.id, 
  criticites.criticite, 
  criticites.etat, 
FROM 
  public.histo_jobs, 
  public.jobs, 
  public.criticites
WHERE 
  histo_jobs.job_id = jobs.id AND
  criticites.jobid = jobs.id;

I created these relations between my models:

```
    Jobs.belongsTo(Criticte ,  {foreignKey : 'jobid'} );
    Criticte.hasMany(Jobs);

    HistoJobs.belongsTo(Jobs, {foreignKey : 'job_id'});
    Jobs.hasMany(HistoJobs);
```

Criticte.find({
            include: [ {model:HistoJobs} , {model: Jobs}, {model: HistoJobs} ],
        }).complete(function(err, resultFound){...

and I got error: 
Error: histo_job is not associated to criticite!.

Can someone help me with this please ?

Thanks a lot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With your current setup I would recommend using nested eager loading. As @dan-rocha already mentioned, you can only eager load models which are directly associated, that's why you are getting the error about histo_jobs not being associated to criticte. There is no direct histojobs belongsTo/hasOne/hasMany criticites.

Try something like:

```
Criticte.find({
    include: [
        { model: Jobs, include: [
            { model: HistoJobs }
        ]}
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this (as long as I know, an object retrieval with an association joined with another association is not available on Sequelize) is creating a raw query and putting the info into a `Criticite`instance

```
var query = "SELECT criticites.id, criticites.criticite, criticites.etat, FROM public.histo_jobs, public.jobs, public.criticites WHERE histo_jobs.job_id = jobs.id AND criticites.jobid = jobs.id";
sequelize
.query(query, Criticites)
.success(function(criticites){
    // Each record will now be mapped to the criticite's DAO-Factory.
    console.log(criticites);
})
```

I don't really understand why would you need that. At calling `Criticite.findAll()` you would be doing

```
SELECT * FROM criticites
```

and putting it into a `Criticite` instance
that is almost the same as calling

```
SELECT criticites.id, criticites.criticite, criticites.etat, FROM public.histo_jobs,public.jobs, public.criticites WHERE histo_jobs.job_id = jobs.id AND criticites.jobid = jobs.id;
```

since you are doing an unused JOIN and selecting every column on your criticites db table.

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You write 'Criticte.hasMany(Jobs);'. But as I see from your structure `Criticte` has only one `Job`. And vice versa `Job` has many `Criticte`, but you write `Job.belongsTo(Criticte)`. Update your question after clearing these things out, please.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is a nested  query like this

```
Criticities.findAll({
             include : [{ 
                          model:Jobs ,
                         include: [ HistoJobs]}
                       ]}).then(result=> {   **** your code here **** })
```